# Do I need to close the connection after doing #isClosed method?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, database-connection

I am wondering if testing the database connection will add up to the connection pool? to make it clear please see my code.

```
try {
    if (conn ==null || conn.isClosed()) {
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
} catch (Exception e){ 
    return false;
}
```

Do I need to add conn.close() after the return? even if it's just connection testing?

Comment: If you are not going to use this conneciton, hten close it. If you need it don't close it.

Comment: its for checking if the connection is available. if its not available it will move on to the next database.

Comment: What do you mean with "will add up to the connection pool"?

Answer (score 0):

If this method is responsible in your design for making sure the connection is closed, then yes, you should close it just to make things clean; there's no sense in letting stale connections pile up. (And you shouldn't be catching `Exception`; catch whatever specific exception is declared, which shouldn't be any here, so that real problem reports don't get eaten.)

Comment: its for checking if the connection is available. if its not available it will move on to the next database. Up vote please hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

> *Do I need to add conn.close() after the return?*

You can't have any piece of code after a **return** statement. It'll be an unreachable code!

> *even if it's just connection testing?*

If its just connection testing, better to close it, as you're not gonna use it further!

Comment: yeah right hahaha before the return I mean. hahahaha sorry for that